# The condition for the existence of a cyclic vector in the diagonal operator A{$x_n$}={$a_nx_n$}

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the diagonal operator $A\{x_n\}$ = $\{a_nx_n\}$. The operator A is defined on the sequence space $\ell_2$. It must be proved that this operator has a cyclic vector if and only if all $\{a_n\}$ are different.

I tried to consider a situation where there are indexes $m$ and $k$, that $a_m=a_k, m \neq k$. Then there is no cyclic vector, because if it existed, two situations would be possible:

1. $x_m = x_k$
2. $x_m \neq x_k$

Then in the first situation $\overline{\text{span}}\{A^n x\}$ consists of vectors with the same coordinates m and k, and in the second situation $\overline{\text{span}}\{A^n x\}$ consists on the contrary of vectors with coordinates $m$ and $k$ are different. Then, in both cases, the definition of the cyclic vector will not be fulfilled and it will not exist. Can you tell me if my reasoning is correct and how can I prove the second part of the statement? Ideologically, it seems clear that if all $a_n$ are different, then you will have a countable number of linearly independent sequences, which means we can approximate an arbitrary sequence with any accuracy, but how to prove it?

Comment: What is the space on which $A$ is defined?

Comment: I think you should assume that $a_n\neq 0$ for all $n.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc $a_n$ can still be zero, because if, for example, we have $a_m$=$a_k$=0, then we understand that only the initial vector has coordinates with numbers k and m nonzero, which means that closing the linear shell will not give us all the space. Otherwise, if we have all $a_n$ different and we want to show that there is a cyclic vector, then we can have only one number k, such that $a_k$=0. Without limitation of generality, let k=1. But then, to approximate the first coordinate for any sequence, we can use an initial cyclic vector whose first coordinate is not zero

Comment: I have forgotten about the identity operator which is included in $A^n$ for $n=0.$ Sorry. I think your question has something to do with the Vanderminde determinants.

Comment: @TomSawyer Yes, you're reasoning is correct. For the second part, use any $x$ consisting only of non-zero elements as a cyclic vector. It suffices to note that for any "prefix" $y_1,\dots,y_k$, there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $p(A)x$ has $y_1,\dots,y_k$ as its first $k$ elements. Such a polynomial can be shown to exist either by appealing to the existence of interpolating polynomials or by using the invertibility of the associated Vandermonde matrix (per Ryszard's suggestion)

Comment: @TomSawyer Or, using [Lagrange polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial), you can explicitly show that the closed span contains the standard basis elements, which is also sufficient

Comment: @BenGrossmann Even if you get $y_1\ldots,y_n$ as the first $n$ coordinates in $p(A)x$, you should estimate other coordinates  of $p(A)x.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc That's a good point